# Sum up function in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, sum

I wanted to sum up the `numofunit` and `total price` in the subject table. I already did what I was told to do on google, however I still encountered some errors which is vague to me. I wanted to know if I am doing this right, since I am still new in querying db in laravel. I honestly am not sure of the syntax

This is a snippet of the query:

```
 $results = DB::table('subjects')
            ->join('subjectblocking', 'subjects.subjectcode', '=', 'subjectblocking.subjectcode')
            ->join('grades', 'subjectblocking.blockcode', '=', 'grades.blockcode')
            ->select('subjects.numofunit as total_units, subjects.price as total_tuition')
            ->sum('subjects.numofunit','subjects.price')
            ->orWhere(function($query)
            {
                $query->where('grades.studentid', '=', '2013-F0218')
                        ->where('sem', '=', '1')
                        ->where('sy', '=', '2013-2014');
            })
            ->get();
```

This is the error that I have encountered:

> Call to a member function orWhere() on a non-object
>   On line 72: which is ->orWhere(function($query)

I believe that I declared `$query`, so i'm not sure why I'm still receiving errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sum` needs to go after all of the where clauses. So just move it to after the `orWhere`, remove the superfluous `get`, and it should work... according the rest of your query is well formed, but it looks okay at first clance at least.

Answer (score 2):

As Joel Hinz mentioned, sum needs to go after all of the where clauses, but he is incorrect when he says it should go just before get(). It should replace get().

```
 $results = DB::table('subjects')
        ->join('subjectblocking', 'subjects.subjectcode', '=', 'subjectblocking.subjectcode')
        ->join('grades', 'subjectblocking.blockcode', '=', 'grades.blockcode')
        ->select('subjects.numofunit as total_units, subjects.price as total_tuition')
        ->orWhere(function($query)
        {
            $query->where('grades.studentid', '=', '2013-F0218')
                    ->where('sem', '=', '1')
                    ->where('sy', '=', '2013-2014');
        })
        ->sum('subjects.numofunit','subjects.price');
```

Comment: Oops, you're right. I'll change my comment accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @ColinSchoen @JoelHinz! I get the syntax now, however after I moved the *->sum('subjects.numofunit','subjects.price');* It caused an error to my return view.